# Blazor App Server - Using Claims in a blazor similar to asp.net core Mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I Used This Code in Blazor :

```
 if (UserAccont.LoginUser(loginuser) != null)
        {
            if (UserAccont.UserIsBlocked(loginuser.Mobile)) 
            {
                UserIsBlocked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                var user = UserAccont.LoginUser(loginuser);
                var claims = new List<Claim>()
                {
                  new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,user.Mobile.ToString()),
                };
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, 
                 CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    IsPersistent = true

                };
                 HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal, properties);
            }
        }
```

But HttpContext was for mvc

How I Can using this Code?

and

I cant use this at the razor view ?

```
 @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
```

please help me?

Answer (score 1):

> But HttpContext was for mvc   How I Can using this Code? and I cant
> use this at the razor view ?
>
> ```
>  @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
> ```

From your code and description, it seems that you are creating an Asp.net Core Blazor server application with cookie Authentication, and now you want to check whether the user is Authenticated or not in the Razor page or Razor component, right?

To get current user details in a Blazor page, we need to inject the dependency `IHttpContextAccessor`.

First, we need to configure the `IHttpContextAccessor` service in the `startup.cs` as follows.

```
  services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Then, in the Blazor component, refer the following method to check if user is authenticated:

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
@inject IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.
<br />

@if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <span> You have authenticated! </span>
}
<br />
@message

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@code{
    private string message;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            message = $"Initialized at {DateTime.Now}";
    }
}
```

The result as below:

[image]

More detail information about creating a Blazor Server side application with Cookie authentication, you can refer this sample: [A Demonstration of Simple Server-side Blazor Cookie Authentication](https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/36)

Comment: But I do not know how to give the value of my model to Identity ?